# 90's horror movie with a haunted house with witchcraft history

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching a movie in the 90s. I've been searching for years but have been unable to find it.

- A family of three moves into a house. Soon they are frightened by visions they see.
- They bring in some people: a specialist in paranormal, some clergy, etc.
- In the basement they find a walled-in corpse.
- They find out the owners of the house were a family involved in witchcraft and the walled corpse was their daughter.
- House exterior is decorated with gargoyles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it myself. It is **[House of the Damned](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116573)** aka **Spectre**

> Will and Maura decide to come to Ireland with their daughter and live on Maura's ancestral estate. But soon weird happenings around the house lead a local priest to confess that Maura's ancestors practiced black magic.

[image: Front cover of *Spectre*]

It's a 1996 movie with a 4.3 imdb score. Might be direct to TV.

### Trailer

Comment: Congrats! How did you find it? I did some searches, but had little luck with the keywords I chose (for a while, I was checking for if there were other books based off of the source material of *A Haunting in Connecticut*). And, of course, don't forget to self-accept in another 43ish hours.

Comment: Times I searched it before, I googled the keywords and asked in some other places. Today, somehow I stumbled upon another find the movie question and posted it here. But did not stop there. I googled keywords again and this time my luck smiled at me.